# Google Maps showed blank sheet in web application

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am pretty new to API and I have been trying to get it running by getting my position and pass it to new google.maps.Map, but it does not show the map. I think I have committed some errors yet the console in javascript didn't show any. Please kindly take a look at my code and see what I should have done. Thank you in advance.

```
var map;

function displayLocation(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var pLocation = document.getElementById("location");
    pLocation.innerHTML = latitude + ", " + longitude;

    showMap(position.coords);
}

function showMap (coords){
    var googleLatLong = {lat: coords.latitude, lng: coords.longitude};
    console.log(googleLatLong);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: googleLatLong,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
    console.log(map);
}


function displayError(error){
    var errors = ["Unknow error", "Permission denied by user", "Position not available", "Timeout error"];
    var message = errors[error.code];
    console.warn("Error in getting your location: " + message, error.message);
}

window.onload = function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, displayError);
    } else {
        alert("Error Occor!");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <style>
    body{
      background-color: #fafafa;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 20px;
    }
    div #map{
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
    }

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Find nearby places</h3>

    <p id="location"></p>
    <div id="map">Loading...</div>



    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey">
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace MyKey

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey">
```

for its key google api

Comment: Hello! I actually have generated the key and put it there, but the still didn't work.

Comment: the variables (coords.latitude, coords.longitude) if they have data?